# How to write the sql select query for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have mssql tabel like this >

```
ID           Code                Rating
1            10                  4
2            10                  5
3            10                  4
4            11                  2
5            11                  3
```

The sql query logic i want ...

I want when i search the record using code 10 then the output would be 4 because the 4 rating would be given most of the time for code 10 ....

and another logic if i search for code 11 then the out put will be 3 because 3 will be most recent rate for code 11...

how to write the sql query for im using ASP.NET ( VB)

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, it's purely a database thing.

Comment: What if you have another code 10 rating 5, i.e. there's no single mode value for code 10? Do you want SQL, or code using a specific ORM e.g. Linq-to-SQL or EF?

Comment: Good point; if you have a tie, then you might want to add more sort criteria to make the result unambiguous; or you might want to do it differently so that both results are shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is filter:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Code = 10
```

You're interested in the 'rating' field:

```
SELECT Rating FROM mytable WHERE Code = 10
```

Now you want to count entries for Rating, which can be achieved using a combination of `GROUP BY` and the `COUNT()` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Rating FROM mytable WHERE Code = 10 GROUP BY Rating
```

Now all that's left is sort by count, descending, and select only the first row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Rating FROM mytable WHERE Code = 10 GROUP BY Rating ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: that is not actually what i want ... i dont wanna count .. how many of the people rate for code 10 ....

Comment: A right, misread the question. The most recent answer is the one with the highest ID (assuming it's an auto-incrementing ID), so all you need to do is `SELECT TOP 1 Rating FROM mytable WHERE Code = 10 ORDER BY ID DESC`

Comment: But i want if u search for code 10 ... then most of the people rate code 10 a rating4 then output for code10 is 4 .... and if search for code11 then you will find the rate is 2 and 3 then we have to display only those rating who entered recently .... and i wanna do this on single code

Comment: Make up your mind. You can't have both. Either you sort by count, or by insert order. Please take the time to think about the requirements first - when do you want to show the most frequent rating, and when do you want the most recent one?